# nginx - putting PHP through TCP instead of sockets

Tags: php, sockets, nginx, tcp

I received error like this bellow:

`2014/07/18 15:01:24 [error] 5700#0: *1 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream, client: 1.2.3.4, server: serv_name.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "serv_name.pl"`

I know to solve this problem I have to put PHP traffic through TCP instead of sockets. Only for one webb application - we have 12 webs running on nginx at the time. How can I do this only for this one speciefied  web app ?

It would be enough to add in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d` directory file `web_name.conf` ?

What should i put into this file ?

---

**I have to add more information because I messed up a bit. Above error is for SQL requests and there occured parallely error 502 which is connected with socket PHP traffic - thats why I wrote about changing sockets into TCP.**

Comment: @symcbean Surely he is referring to unix sockets in this context.

Comment: I can`t agree with You. TCP is an layer 4 protocol and socket is a pair of Layer 3 address and Layer 4 protocol communication thread ID - for example IP/TCP what means that in this case socket is a pair of IP address and TCP port.

Comment: Oh, now I read about context XD Ok, You have right :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to switch to TCP... in fact, you will end up with a performance penalty for doing so.  All you need to do is increase your buffer sizes.

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 8k;
```

You can increase this as needed for your application.  You can also change the size of the buffer, but there is no reason to do this as it will automatically pick based on the page size for your system.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffers

Comment: Where should I change it ? We have multiple web aps at our nginx.  It would be ok to increase this buffer for all projects ? It makes any differance ?

Comment: I don't see any harm in setting it broadly.  Your server will use more memory, but we're not talking about a ton of memory here.

Comment: Where I should make this parameter change ? There would be only one place ?

Comment: @user3799089 You should set this along with the rest of your FastCGI settings.

Comment: So i should add `fastcgi_buffers 16;` into a file


`/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`

at the end and at the bottom of this configuration file ?

Comment: I edited a bellow config file:


`/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`

I added `fastcgi_buffers 16;` and there was error occured durring `service nginx restart` . I had to remove this line from configuration file.

Comment: @user3799089 These settings are different depending on your Nginx version.  Read the documentation in the link above, and check your Nginx version with `nginx -V`.

Comment: I have `nginx version: nginx/1.6.0`

At Your link I don`t see any devides which depend of versions. 

Writing `fastcgi_buffers 16;` did You mean `fastcgi_buffer_size size;` or `fastcgi_buffers number size;` ?

Comment: @user3799089 Ah I thought the buffer size was optional.  My mistake.  Try `fastcgi_buffers 16 8k;`.  You will need to tweak this value to work for your application.

Comment: I set `fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;` We would se would it work tomorrow :)

Comment: @user3799089 You shouldn't set `fastcgi_buffer_size` when you've already set it with `fastcgi_buffers`.

Comment: Why ? One parameter vail another ? Which option shlould be the best in my case ?

Comment: You can use either, but specifying 128k in one directive and 16k in the other is non-sensical.  `fastcgi_buffers 8 128k` is the same as setting `fastcgi_buffer_size 128k`, in addition to allocating 8 of them.

Comment: When I use `fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;` and I want restart nginx there is error occured - restart is FAILED.

Comment: Well, there should be more details in your logs then.  In any case, you only need `fastcgi_buffers`.

Comment: I think that error cause was fact I were making changes at fastcgi_params file instead of file with my application nginx configuration.